# How i can make pattern in input type="tel" start with only "05"?

Tags: html, regex

Hi everyone as I said in the title How I can make pattern start with only "05", I want it to accept 05[any 8 number you can think of it]

I tried several ways but none of them work with me like

`pattern=/ (05) \ d {9}/`

`pattern="[05]{1} [0-9]{9}"/`

`pattern="[05]{10}"/` (this one work but only with Any combination that contains 0 and 5)

`pattern=/ (0) \/ (5) \ {8} /`

Comment: Please update tag to regex; this is NOT an html question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use start and end of string symbols, use `{8}`, not `{9}`:

```html
pattern='/^05\d{8}$/'
```

[Examples](https://regex101.com/r/CPbpzL/1)

---

I think your tries mostly does not work because you have whitespaces inside patter:

`/ (05) \ d {9}/` - *space*, sequence `05`, *space*, escaped literal *space* 9 times
`pattern="[05]{1} [0-9]{9}"/` - no even valid HTML as `/` is outside quotes and does not have start/end delimiters
`[05]{10}` - any sequence of 0 or 5, 10 times. E.g. `0000000000`
`(0) / (5) \ {8}` - *space*, `0`, *space*, *backslash*, *space*, 5, escaped *space* 8 times

Comment: thank you for you answer I try it but it give this "Please match the required format"

Comment: this is the full code `<input type="tel" placeholder="0545555555"  maxlength="10"  pattern='/^05\d{8}$/'><br>`

Comment: @randomman Try just `pattern="05\d{8}"`

Comment: thank you thank you million time, Finally it worked well